# Draw Arrow in mid point of links such that the arrow is placed according to the start node and end node

Tags: vb.net, vector, graphics, computational-geometry, vector-graphics

I want to Draw an arrow at Mid Point of a Link (which is pipe with start and end Node). It will have flow in it.
i have written a vb code for solving this task but i am stuck on a point where the Arrow head changes its direction if Quadrant is Changed.
Actually i want to Draw an Forward arrow if the user starts from Start_Node and Ends On End_Node and similarly a Backward Arrow if user starts from End_Node and Ends in Start_Node.
if have the drawing ctrl with:  +X in Right Side and +Y in Downward Side.

```
    Private Sub DrawArrowInPipes(ctrl As MapControl, g As Graphics)
    Dim arrowpen As New Pen(Brushes.Yellow, 3)
    Dim rotationangle As Double = GetInclination '
    'If rotationangle < 0 Then rotationangle = 360 - rotationangle
    '   rotationangle = 360 - GetInclination
    Dim midp As PointF = ctrl.ToScreenCoordinates(MidPoint)
    Dim arrowvector As Vector2D = New Vector2D(15, 0)
    If flow < 0 Then rotationangle += 180

    Dim side1 As Double = 180 + 45
    Dim side2 As Double = 180 - 45

    Dim p1 As PointF = midp + arrowvector.Rotate(side1)
    Dim p2 As PointF = midp + arrowvector.Rotate(side2)

    ' If flow <> 0 Then g.DrawLines(arrowpen, New PointF() {p1, midp, p2})
    g.DrawLines(arrowpen, New PointF() {p1, midp, p2})
End Sub

   <Browsable(False)>
Public ReadOnly Property GetInclination() As Double
    Get
        Dim V1 As Vector2D = EndNode.DrawnPosition - StartNode.DrawnPosition
        Return Math.Atan2(V1.Y, V1.X) * 180 / Math.PI
    End Get
End Property
```

Help needed.

Solved With :

```
 Private Sub DrawArrowInPipes(ctrl As SwMapControl, g As Graphics)
    Dim arrowpen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(167, 25, 48), 2)
    Dim rotationangle As Double = 360 - GetInclination
    Dim midp As PointF = ctrl.ToScreenCoordinates(MidPoint)
    Dim arrowvector As Vector2D = New Vector2D(10, 0)

    If flow < 0 Then rotationangle += 180

    Dim p1 As PointF = midp + arrowvector.Rotate(rotationangle + 45 + 180)
    Dim p2 As PointF = midp + arrowvector.Rotate(rotationangle - 45 + 180)

    g.DrawLines(arrowpen, New PointF() {p1, midp, p2})
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might need to review your question a bit.  It's not particularly clear to me what you're asking.  Also the code you've given us doesn't look to be complete so no body here is really going to be able to help

Comment: I m really very sorry that i couldn't explain clearly. I have solved it myself. Actually my problem was Connecting Two Nodes [Start Node and End Node] with a line which has direction arrow in mid, Such that the direction must be forward arrow if it is connection from Start Node to End node and vice versa. Thank you.